# Cannot Write Image to USB drive using usb-creator-gtk

Tags: usb

When I select the disk image using the "other" button, it doesn't appear in the list. Any ideas? I am trying to make a USB startup disk for Android 3.2 from android-x86.org, the image size is 184 MB. The drive I am using is 8 GB`and appears in the list in usb-creator-gtk. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be the iso has not been made compatible with usb-creator method of writing images.  You could always just dd it,  `sudo dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdX` X = usb drive (be careful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to use Unetbootin for Ubuntu, an application with all the features of usb-creator-gtk and more. It can be downloaded at unetbootin.sourceforge.net and it is a completely free and open-source application. I, however, am still disappointed that usb-creator-gtk can't handle this image, as Unetbootin handled it gracefully without complaining.

Comment: I too am a little disappointed that it cannot handle Solaris .iso either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you have the complete file.iso of Android (not maybe partial like file.iso.part) , check if you're looking in the right folder and if 'CD image' is selected on lower right corner of file selection window, appeared after clicking 'other' button.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I have done both of those things and it still will not work.